# Execute text in Postgresql database as Python code

Tags: python, postgresql

If I have text that is saved in a Postgresql database is there any way to execute that text as Python code and potentially have it update the same database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That sounds terrifying.
2. Yes, [plpy](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpython-database.html)

PL/Python is a extension for postgres that lets you write functions in python. You may have to install the extension from your package manager or it may have been bundled in already when you installed postgres (this depends on how you installed postgres `apt-get install  postgresql-plpython-9.1` in debian).

To enable the extension in your database first use psql to run:

```
CREATE EXTENSION plpythonu
```

Now you can specify functions with python so you could write a function to execute that code like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION eval_python(code text) RETURNS integer AS $$
    eval(code)
    return 1
$$ LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

And execute it for every `code` field in `my_table` like:

```
SELECT eval_python(code) FROM my_table;
```

Read the docs on [PL/python](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpython.html) for more details on how to interact with the db from python.

Comment: Don't see anything on your plpy link that would suggest that it can do what I asked. Do you have an example?

Comment: Updated with an example, but without knowing more about the real issue it's a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

let me see if I understand what you are trying to accomplish:

1. store ad-hoc user code in a varchar field on a database
2. read and execute said code
3. allow said code to affect the database in question, say `drop table ...`

Assuming that I've got it, you could write something that

1. reads the table holding the code (use `pyodbc` or something)
2. runs an `eval` on what was pulled from the db - this will let you execute ANY code, including self updating code

are you sure this is what you want to do?